# Trying to console log this function to retrieve an attribute node from an <a> element

Tags: function, attributes

I am trying to console log this code and can't seem to get it to work anyway.

Here is my Javscript function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("myAnchor");
  var attr = elmnt.getAttributeNode("target").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = attr;
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="dom_obj_attributes.asp" target="_blank">Attr object</a>.

<p>Click the button to display the value of the target attribute node of the link above.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

the return value should be: _blank

Comment: Hi, perhaps log the element to see if it matches what you expected?

Comment: It worked for me using Chrome and dev tools

Comment: What I mean is that I don't know the correct keywords to use to console log it out

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

console.log(myAnchor.getAttributeNode("target"));